# How to make certain text not selectable with CSS

Tags: css

The header for my page has some centered text, but I do not want the user to be able to select it. Is there a way to do this with CSS?

Answer (score 725, accepted):

The CSS below stops users from being able to select text.

```
-webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */        
-moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
-ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+/Edge */
user-select: none; /* Standard */
```

To target IE9 downwards the html attribute `unselectable` must be used instead:

```
<p unselectable="on">Test Text</p>
```

Comment: And does the `unselectable` attribute work in all browsers?

Comment: it does not work for mobile browsers

Comment: @Fabián no i tested and it does not work on chrome

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks. And for good measure, I like to add: `cursor: default;`

Comment: As of 2016, as simple `user-select` is enough now.

Comment: @KonstantinSchubert not on Firefox 49.0.2 (released October 2016), which still requires `-moz-user-select`.

Comment: It works on Chrome. thanks.

Comment: It looks like Safari still requires `-webkit-user-select: none;` Kind of annoying...

Answer (score 35):

Use a simple background image for the textarea suffice.

Or

```
<div onselectstart="return false">your text</div>
```