# How to capture mouseup event outside of mousedown element? (i.e. for proper Drag-n-Drop?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, onmouseup

The [Javascript `onmouseup` event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseup.asp) is not triggered if the mouse button is released outside the element on which `onmousedown` has been triggered.

This causes a drag&drop bug in JQuery UI: A JQuery [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) element does not stop dragging when mouse button is released outside of its container (because the element will stop moving when reaching it's parent boundaries). Steps to reproduce:

- Go to http://jqueryui.com/draggable/.
- Drag the draggable downward until the mouse has left the surrounding container
- Release mouse button (no mouse button is pressed at this point)
- Move mouse back into container
- And the draggable is still being dragged. I would expect the dragging to have stopped as soon as I released the mouse button - *no matter* where it is released.

I see that behavior in latest Chrome and IE.

Is there any work-around?

I know that we could stop dragging the container on `mouseout` or `mouseleave`, but I would like to keep dragging, even if I am outside the parent container, much like in [google maps](https://www.google.com/maps) (no matter, where you release the mouse, it always stops dragging the map).

Comment: `containment:'parent'` ???  http://jsfiddle.net/4wX58/

Comment: PS: I see that when mouse button is released outside of document, element is still draggable :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have your mousedown element "capture" the pointer. Then it would always receive the mouseup event. In React this could look like this:

```tsx
const onPointerDownDiv1 = (event: React.PointerEvent) => {
  (event.target as HTMLDivElement).setPointerCapture(event.pointerId);
  // Do something ...
};

const onPointerUpDiv1 = (event: React.PointerEvent) => {
  (event.target as HTMLDivElement).releasePointerCapture(event.pointerId);
  // Do something ...
};
```

```tsx
<div
  ref={div1}
  id="div1"
  className="absolute top-[200px] left-[390px] h-8 w-8 bg-red-300"
  onPointerDown={onPointerDownDiv1}
  onPointerUp={onPointerUpDiv1}
/>
```

And here is an implementation using "plain vanilla" html + javascript:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div
      id="div1"
      style="
        position: absolute;
        left: 50px;
        top: 50px;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background-color: red;
      "
    ></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    let isDragging = false;
    let offsetX = 0;
    let offsetY = 0;
    let divElement = document.getElementById("div1");

    divElement.addEventListener("pointerdown", onPointerDown);
    divElement.addEventListener("pointermove", onPointerMove);
    divElement.addEventListener("pointerup", onPointerUp);

    function onPointerDown(event) {
      divElement.setPointerCapture(event.pointerId);
      offsetX = event.clientX - divElement.offsetLeft;
      offsetY = event.clientY - divElement.offsetTop;
      isDragging = true;
    }

    function onPointerMove(event) {
      if (isDragging) {
        divElement.style.left = (event.clientX - offsetX).toString() + "px";
        divElement.style.top = (event.clientY - offsetY).toString() + "px";
      }
    }

    function onPointerUp(event) {
      divElement.releasePointerCapture(event.pointerId);
      isDragging = false;
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks interesting. Sadly, this Q is not about `react`. Also, your code does not address dragging of elements. Can you remove the `react` dependency and illustrate how this can be used to stop dragging an object?

Comment: I have added a "plain vanilla" html + javascript version of my solution in my previous answer. You should be able to copy and paste it into an html-file and run it directly in any browser of you choice. You should be able to drag html element "div1" around with propper start and stop of the dragging action.

Comment: JSFiddle possible? Or any runnable snippet?

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/bassman21/crk7p4jb. The runnable "snippet" is also in my previous answer. I will add another another answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my own answer to point to yours. I would recommend adding some linkage. Either way, good catch! The [setPointerCapture API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setPointerCapture) did not exist back then. [Chrome 55](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-chrome-55/) was one of the earliest to support it and that's from 2016, while this Q was from 2014.

Comment: Works great in React.

Answer (score 4):

I found this to be the best solution: Attach the `mouseup` event handler to `document` instead. Then it will always cancel, even if you release the mouse button outside the browser. Of course, this is not a pretty solution, but apparently, this is the only way to get dragging to work correctly.

Try the solution below:

- You will see that "Drag END" will always happen, no matter where you release the cursor.
- Also, in order to prevent text selection while dragging, I added an [`unselectable` class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900124/how-to-make-certain-text-not-selectable-with-css).

```js
let dragging = false;
const dragEl = document.querySelector('div');
const logEl = document.querySelector('pre');

dragEl.addEventListener('mousedown touchstart', (evt) => {
  dragging = true;
  dragEl.classList.add('unselectable');
  logEl.textContent += 'drag START\n';
});
document.addEventListener('mouseup touchend', (evt) => {
  if (dragging) {
    event.preventDefault();
    dragEl.classList.remove('unselectable');
    dragging = false;
    logEl.textContent += 'drag END\n';
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
}

.unselectable {
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */        
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+/Edge */
  user-select: none; /* Standard */
}
```

```html
<div>drag me</div>
<hr>
LOG:
<p><pre></pre></p>
```

## Update

These days, [the `setPointerCapture` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setPointerCapture) provides a cleaner solution, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71643994/2228771).

Comment: Thanks, I was just looking for how to keep track of the cursor outside the document (or if there was a way) and saw this. I didn't notice that Google maps did it, even though I've noticed some other sites don't, and it's annoying when they don't. Anyway, thanks for posting your own answer, it helped me out!

Comment: This does just move the problem up and you get the same issue if you release the mouse button outside of the document (or window). This can be overcome with the solution in my answer.

Comment: @Mog0 Not sure what you are basing your claims on? Have you even tried it?

Comment: I did try it. However, pay attention to the dates - my answer was nearly 7.5 years ago and the modern browsers are very different now. Note my solution below had issues with compatibility between IE8 and Firefox!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to handle this is to check the current button status in the mousemove event handler. If the button is no longer down, stop dragging.

If you put the mouseup event on the document then you just move the problem up, the original problem will still show itself if you release the button outside of the document (or even outside of the browser window).

For example with jQuery

```
$div.on("mousedown", function (evt) {
        dragging = true;
  }).on("mouseup", function (evt) {
        dragging = false;
  }).on("mousemove", function (evt) {
        if (dragging && evt.button == 0) {
            //Catch case where button released outside of div
            dragging = false;
        }
        if (dragging) {
          //handle dragging here
        }
  });
```

You could skip the mouseup event handler because it will be caught by the mousemove but I think it's more readable with it still there.

Comment: I like this solution better, except I found that the property (on Firefox at least) was mouse.buttons, not mouse.button. mouse.button was always 0 for me

Comment: @ErinDrummond Well spotted. evt.button == 0 means no button on IE <= 8 but left button on Firefox and newer IE.
evt.buttons however is only available on IE9+ and Firefox and unsupported on Chrome, Safari and Opera.

Comment: This solution still only sets `dragging` to `false` when the mouse is on the element, not outside of it. Also, contrary to your claims, the `document` event handler is different from all other event handlers, because it is **NOT** restricted to the `document` or even the browser window, and will **ALWAYS** trigger immediately, no matter where you stop dragging.

Comment: @Domi - This is a very old discussion and down voting an answer after 6 years of browser development would seem to me to be very unfair. The answer was based on the situation at the time when using IE7/8 and equivalents so I would not be at all surprised if modern browsers behave differently as the specs have changed significantly in that time.

Comment: This part did not change. I downvoted because it never solved the problem stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an "index.html" file with the following code in it (you can just copy and paste it entirely) it will show the working solution using just plain vanilla html + javascript.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div
      id="div1"
      style="
        position: absolute;
        left: 50px;
        top: 50px;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background-color: red;
      "
    ></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    let isDragging = false;
    let offsetX = 0;
    let offsetY = 0;
    let divElement = document.getElementById("div1");

    divElement.addEventListener("pointerdown", onPointerDown);
    divElement.addEventListener("pointermove", onPointerMove);
    divElement.addEventListener("pointerup", onPointerUp);

    function onPointerDown(event) {
      divElement.setPointerCapture(event.pointerId);
      offsetX = event.clientX - divElement.offsetLeft;
      offsetY = event.clientY - divElement.offsetTop;
      isDragging = true;
    }

    function onPointerMove(event) {
      if (isDragging) {
        let newPosLeft = event.clientX - offsetX;
        if (newPosLeft < 30) {
          newPosLeft = 30;
        }
        let newPosTop = event.clientY - offsetY;
        if (newPosTop < 30) {
          newPosTop = 30;
        }
        divElement.style.left = newPosLeft.toString() + "px";
        divElement.style.top = newPosTop.toString() + "px";
      }
    }

    function onPointerUp(event) {
      divElement.releasePointerCapture(event.pointerId);
      isDragging = false;
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I have added on purpose the limitations regarding the absolute position of the dragged element. That allows you to see that the mouseup event is captured even if the mouse pointer is not over it.